# jQuery, converting from a .POST to .AJAX with a method?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
    $.post(this.href, { _method: 'delete' }, null, "script");
```

How can I convert that to a:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ,
    data: ,
    beforeSend: function() {
    },
    success: function() {
```

I'm not use how to deal with URL or how to add the _method: 'delete' where does that go with .ajax?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL is going to remain the same, and the _method:'delete' is going to go into the data section:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: this.href,
    data: { _method: 'delete' },
    beforeSend: function() {},
    success: function() {},
    dataType: 'script'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

[documentation of $.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here's an example of a method i use in my application, note the URL and data parameters will be your this.href and _methods:"delete"

```
function OnChangeRoom(RoomID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../server.asmx/GetWordFromRoomID",
        data: "{'RoomID':'" + RoomID + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d.length == 0)
                $('#spanWord').html(' ');
            else
                $('#spanWord').html('Word: ' + data.d);
        }
    });
}
```